# How to register service in symfony 2.1

Tags: bundle, symfony-2.1

I am using Symfony 2.1 and I want to add a new bundle. The bundle is called `pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle` this bundle is added to composer.json as any other bundle: in require array is added line `"pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle": "dev-master"`

After running php composer.phar update process ended with success. After that was bundle registered in appkernel.php.

The problem begins with registering this bundle as service. In readme of this bundle is written:

```
 dubture_f_fmpeg:
    binary: /usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

But Symfony crashes with error code

```
 InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "binary" under "dubture_f_fmpeg"
```

Has anyone succesfully configured this bundle and how? Or any other bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the readme. The correct configuration goes like this:

```
dubture_f_fmpeg:
    ffmpeg_binary: /usr/bin/ffmpeg
    ffprobe_binary: /usr/bin/ffprobe
```

As you can see you also have to define the `ffprobe_binary`.

You can chek the bundle's configuration options in the [Configuration.php](https://github.com/pulse00/ffmpeg-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) file.

Or dump the bundle's configuration:

```
$ php app/console config:dump-reference DubtureFFmpegBundle

Default configuration for "DubtureFFmpegBundle"

    dubture_f_fmpeg:
        ffmpeg_binary:        ~ # Required
        ffprobe_binary:       ~ # Required
```